# Segmentation Fault after print

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

With the following code:

```
for (i=0;i<mem_size;i++){
    if (mem[i] == l_priority_num){
      printf("\nline1\n");
      printf("line2");
      return i;
    }
}
```

Onto the command line, "line1" gets printed, but afterwards there is a "Segmentation fault". How is this possible?

Comment: How have you initialized `mem`?

Comment: The segmentation fault is coming from code you have not shown us.  If `line1` gets printed, then `line2` also gets printed and then `return i;` is executed.  Control leaves this code and goes somewhere else in your program.

Comment: More code needed: What is `mem`, what is `mem_size`?  What is the surrounding code?  Not enough info here to really help much.

Comment: It's probably not in this code. `line2` is stuck in the buffer, it would be print on newline, when buffer would be filled, when you would explicitly flush buffer or when program would exit. But there was segfault and it got missed.

Answer (score 5):

Because `"line2"` does not have any `"\n"` it will probably not get flushed so you will only see `"\nline1\n"` even though `printf("line2")` most likely was called before the segfault.

Comment: Generally printf needs a \n to print. Otherwise it bufferizes and prints at the end of the program. And @db2791 if you want to know where the segmentation fault is coming from, post more code. Not enough there.